# How to queue packets received on socket connection for processing and UI update in the order received

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, sockets

I have a user application which is reading data from a socket and does some parsing before updating a table. The format of the data coming in is several lines of csv being transmitted roughly every second. My current implementation for my Connection class is included below.

The handleDetectionEvent() on the UI uses a worker thread for parsing the line appropriately and updating the table accordingly. The problem I'm having is that each new line generates a new worker thread and I have no guarantee that the table will be updated in the order of the packets received, so two updates for the same item in the table could result in the earlier one being displayed as the latest update. How can I prevent this?

```
public class Connection implements Runnable {

        private Socket socket;
        private BufferedReader bufferedReader;
        DetectionManager manager;

        public Connection(String sIpAddress, int iPortNumber) throws UnknownHostException, IOException{
            socket = new Socket(sIpAddress, iPortNumber);
        }


        public void run(){
                try {
                    String sCurrentLine;
                    bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                    while ((sCurrentLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {                    
                        if (Thread.interrupted()){
                            closeConnection();
                            return;
                        }                           
                        manager.mUI.handleDetectionEvent(sCurrentLine);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }


        private void closeConnection(){
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You don't need any worker threads. You simply need a thread which reads all from the socket, and when you get a line you need to use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` to synchronize with the EDT (event dispatcher thread).

Comment: But then where is the parsing done?

Comment: You can create the table row in your socket-connector thread but adding to table (model) must be performed in EDT.

Comment: And if the time taken to parse a row exceeds the time interval between successive rows appearing on the socket will these automatically queue up so that no rows are lost, given the current implementation?

Comment: I don't know whether socket can buffer the input data. But if not, you can move the parsing into another thread (sse the class java.util.concurrent.Executors) and from this new thread you can notify EDT using the invokeLater call.

Comment: That's exactly what I ended up doing :) Thank you very much for your input.